# Populating scipy.sparse.coo_matrix with 1s, getting a 2 in there

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Here is my code

```
side = max(df['col1'].max(), df['col2'].max())+1
data = np.ones(2*len(df))
print (sum(data), 2*len(df), max(data))
# prints 738 738 1.0
x = list(df['col1']) + list(df['col2'])
y = list(df['col2']) + list(df['col1'])

mat = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((data,(x,y)), shape=(side, side))
print (mat.sum(), mat.max())
# prints 738 2
```

I don't understand how can the value 2 get into the mat sparse matrix?

Comment: Probably because there are duplicate coordinates.  Duplicates are summed.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the case.